# How do I design a chart of accounts for an accounting system using PHP

Tags: php, treeview

Currently, I am designing and programming an accounting system, and I want to design a tree of accounting accounts, and I do not know the appropriate method for that. I just want to suggest the appropriate way to do that, or refer to any link on this site that explains the appropriate method and the general idea that can help me in this regard, noting that the tree must accept Infinite nodes with the possibility of deleting or modifying the elements of the tree, and I want to know how many schedules I have adopted to do this. I will attach a picture below of the shape of the tree to be designed so that the idea becomes clear

[image: like thise treview]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm, a tree like this is not the most challenging programming task. This makes me wonder how far you got with designing and programming your accounting system? Did you start at all? Did you design a database schema? Are the ledgers themselves done? What do you want to do with the data in accounts you want to delete? A tree like this is rendered line by line whereby you keep track of the level you're at and whether a level has child nodes. It's that simple.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have designed the chart of accounts, but in another way, which is by displaying in a regular table so that only 4 levels of accounts are displayed, and this is the problem that makes me think of using the tree method that includes adding infinite levels, or rather 6 levels at most, I have designed a table Only one contains 4 levels, a main level and 3 sub-levels. Can you point me to a good way to explain the method of designing a tree that includes the possibility of adding infinite levels and branches as in the picture?

Comment: I don't know of a link to where such a chart is explained, but they are relatively simple. It's made out lines. Suppose you need to render the second line for "Application of funds". The level is 1 deep and there are children. So an open folder hangs from the first vertical line. That's followed by the title, and the rest. Now the third line, for "Current Assets". The level is 2 deep and there are no children. So it needs one vertical line, and a closed folder hangs from the second line. Again followed by the title, and the rest. And so on. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: It does get more complicated if you want to allow the user to open and close the folders.

Comment: If you want a more useful answer you should ask a question in which you present the accounts data you have, the output you want, and preferably an attempt at doing it yourself. That way we have something to work with. Question without any code often don't really get anywhere.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I want the user to open and close the folders, note the new photos that I have added in my post now

Comment: I googled _"tree view in php"_ and found, among others: [How to Create Dynamic Tree View Menu in PHP](https://www.phpzag.com/how-to-create-dynamic-tree-view-menu-in-php/) and [TreeView in Javascript](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/demos/#/bootstrap5/treeview/default.html). Does something like this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a hierarchical data model like a nested set or a closure table. In this approach, each node in the tree is represented as a row in a database table, and the relationship between nodes is encoded using additional columns in the table. This approach allows for efficient querying of the tree structure and is suitable for handling a large number of nodes. Or you may use a recursive data model, where each node in the tree is represented as an object that contains a list of its child nodes. This approach is simpler and more intuitive to work with, but may be less efficient for large trees.
You may also want to have a look at some APIs like Java Tree API and their documentation to get some more insight about the idea.

Comment: Could you please send me a video link or a link posted on the Internet explaining this

Comment: you may start having a look at this: https://pear.php.net/package/DB_NestedSet